# How to display two numbers in minute in android

Tags: android, timepicker

I´m trying to display the "two numbers" of minute in my code with an Android TimePicker. But I didn´t get it yet...  The time is only displayed in this format X:X. For example 9:05 will show in my app 9:5.

Can anyone help me please?

This is my code...

```
idtime.setText(new StringBuilder()
         .append(String.valueOf(mHour)).append(":")
         .append(String.valueOf(mMinute)).toString());
```

Answer (score 11):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Example:

Suppose you are displaying the current time:

```
Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM");
String output = sf.format(date).toString();

idtime.setText(output);
```

Another easier method to do zero-padding, you can use `String.format`:

```
String output = String.format("%02d:%02d", mHour, mMinute);
idtime.setText(output);
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot. Perhaps you could expand your answer to provide a worked example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this...

```
if (minute < 10) {
     hour.setText(hour + ":0" + minute);
} else {
     hour.setText(hour + ":" + minute);
}
```

inside TimePicker

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getDuration(long milliseconds) {
        long sec = (milliseconds / 1000) % 60;
        long min = (milliseconds / (60 * 1000))%60;
        long hour = milliseconds / (60 * 60 * 1000);

        String s = (sec < 10) ? "0" + sec : "" + sec;
        String m = (min < 10) ? "0" + min : "" + min;
        String h = "" + hour;

        String time = "";
        if(hour > 0) {
            time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
        } else {
            time = m + ":" + s;
        }
        return time;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can format the date using simple formatter it will return the value in double digit

```
            val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
            val date = formatter.parse(start)
            var output = ""
            val formatter1 = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm")
            output = formatter1.format(date)
```